# Issue with calling function and returning correct char

Tags: java, class, methods, client

Basically what i am creating is a simple game where the user defines the grid sizes and the clicks on boxes to collect points, there are three options Prize= 200 points, Bandit= -100 points and bomb= -10000(which will end the game).

The problem I am getting is when the user selects a box a bomb comes up its only subtracting 100 points like it would if the user selected bandit

BlockHop:

```
import java.util.*;

public class BlockHop{
  Random rand = new Random();
  private GameItems[][] board;
  public static int score = 0;

  public BlockHop(){
    board = new GameItems[1][1];
    board[0][0] = new Prize(0, 0, 'P');
  }
  public BlockHop(int gridSize) {
    board = new GameItems[gridSize][gridSize];
    int end = 10;
    int start = 1;
    for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++){
      for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++){
        int num = rand.nextInt(end - start + 1) + start;
        switch (num){
          case 1:
          case 2:
          case 3:
          case 4:
          case 5:
          case 6:
          board[row][col] = new Prize(row, col, 'P');
          break;
          case 7:
          board[row][col] = new Bomb(row, col, 'X');
          break;
          case 8:
          case 9:
          case 10:
          board[row][col] = new Bandit(row, col, 'B');
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  public void play(int row, int col){
    String newID = getLabel(row, col);
    board[row][col].adjustScore(newID.charAt(0));
  }
  public int getScore(){
    return score;
  }
  public String getLabel(int row, int col){
    if ((board[row][col]).equals('P')){
      return "PRIZE!";
    }
    else if ((board[row][col]).equals('X')){
      return "Bomb!";
    }
    else{
      return "Bandit!";
    }
  }
  public boolean isGameOver(){
      return getScore() < 0;
  }
}
```

GameItems:

```
public abstract class GameItems {

  private final char ID;
  private final int row;      
  private final int col;    
  public GameItems(){
    row = 0;
    col = 0;
    ID = ' ';
  }
  public GameItems(int newRow, int newCol, char newId){
    row = newRow;
    col = newCol;
    ID = newId;
    }
  boolean equals(char c){
    return c == ID;
    }
  public int adjustScore(char input){
    switch (input){
      case 'P':
        BlockHop.score += 200;
        break;
      case 'X':
        BlockHop.score -= -10000;
        break;
      case 'B':
        BlockHop.score -= 100;
        break;
    }
    return BlockHop.score;
  }
}
```

BlockHopGUI:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class BlockHopGUI extends JFrame{

  private BlockHop bh;
  private JButton [][] board;
  private JLabel scorePoints;
  private PlayHandler ph;  // listener for buttons

  public BlockHopGUI( int gridSize ) {
    super( "Click to uncover prizes" );
    bh = new BlockHop( gridSize );
    System.out.println( "gridsize: " + gridSize );
    Container c = getContentPane( );
    JPanel p = new JPanel( );
    board = new JButton[gridSize][gridSize];
    p.setLayout( new GridLayout( gridSize, gridSize ) );

    ph = new PlayHandler( );
    for ( int row = 0; row < board.length; row++ )
      for ( int col = 0; col < board.length; col++ ) {
          board[row][col] = new JButton( "" );
          board[row][col].addActionListener(ph);
          p.add( board[row][col] );
    }
    c.add( p, BorderLayout.CENTER );

    JPanel scorePanel = new JPanel( );
    JLabel scoreLabel = new JLabel( "Score: " );
    scorePoints = new JLabel( Integer.toString( bh.getScore( ) ) );
    scorePanel.add( scoreLabel );
    scorePanel.add( scorePoints );

    c.add( scorePanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

    setSize( 500, 500 );
    setVisible( true );  
  }

  private class PlayHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae ) {
      for ( int row = 0; row < board.length; row++ )
        for ( int col = 0; col < board[0].length; col++ ) {
        if ( ae.getSource( ) == board[row][col] ) {
             bh.play( row, col );
             board[row][col].setText( bh.getLabel( row, col ) );
             board[row][col].removeActionListener( ph );
             break;
        }
      }
      scorePoints.setText(  Integer.toString( bh.getScore( ) ) );
      if ( bh.isGameOver( ) ) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Game over! Final points: "
                                        + bh.getScore( ) );
        System.exit( 1 );  
      }
    }
  }
  public static void main( String [] args ) {
    int gridSize = Integer.parseInt(
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Enter the grid size" ) );
    BlockHopGUI bhg = new BlockHopGUI( gridSize );
    bhg.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged and found the invalid part? Then post it here, you don't get general any code review.

Comment: hold on this will take a bit

Comment: What does any debugging say, when selecting a bomb and entering the `adjustScore`-method?

Answer (score 1):

Your adjustScore() function takes in a char and expects it to be the char marking what the object is in the map, i.e X for bomb, B for bandit, etc. But if you look at where you're calling it in play() that's not what you're actually sending in, you're taking the first char from the label of the square. Normally this would fail completely, but because Bandit and Bomb both start with B and B is one of the chars you're expecting it treats both as a Bandit. You need to fix it so that you're calling a function which returns the char you expect, or change your adjustScore function to take in the whole String label.

Some general tips for debugging are to look at the functions related to the problem and check very carefully that they're doing what you expect, try going through what the program would do step by step and write down variables as they change.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That helps but i thought i had that fixed?

Comment: It doesn't look like it, the problem is these two lines:
    String newID = getLabel(row, col);
    board[row][col].adjustScore(newID.charAt(0));

Comment: ah i see it now, but how do i put getLabel into the second line

Comment: Well, you're actually calling adjustScore() on the actual GameItem within that square of the grid. So you don't have to pass in the char at all, change your adjustScore() function to take in no parameters and where you're switching on the input instead switch on that objects ID. Which you can get with just ID, or this.ID to be more explicit.

Comment: The other option would be to make adjustScore() take in a String instead of a char, like adjustScore(String input), and have your switch cases check the full label like case "Bandit". Then just pass in newID without any changes. 
If this is what you want then really adjustScore should be a static method, and you'd call it with GameItems.adjustScore(newID);

Comment: Thats what i've been stuck with and keep fiddling around and getting no where

Comment: Error: method adjustScore in class GameItems cannot be applied to given types;
  required: char
  found: java.lang.String
  reason: actual argument java.lang.String cannot be converted to char by method invocation conversion

Comment: That seems to be saying that you've changed your function call to pass in a String but haven't changed the function itself to accept a String instead of a char, check the input parameters of the adjustScore function.

Comment: the intput parameters in adjustScore are char?

Comment: Well according to that error you posted, when you call the method you're sending in a String instead. I'm afraid that I can't really work it all out with you in the comments, I'd suggest taking a step back, waiting a bit, then coming back to your code fresh and going over it carefully thinking about what you actually want to pass where and what types to use. Adding comments to your functions would probably help you focus your ideas of what they should do, as well as making it more readable.

Comment: I wouldnt have posted it if i didnt spend time trying to figure it out... I'm still unsure on what i'm needing to do..